# TFJS throws TS2411 as error when importing using Typescript

Tags: typescript, tensorflow.js

I try to import tfjs in a Typescript environment. However, I get the following error:

> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/keras_format/types.d.ts:12:5 - error TS2411: Property 'config' of type 'T' is not assignable to string index type 'PyJsonValue'.

This can be easily reproduced with the following steps:

```
npm init
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs
npm i typescript
```

Create a index.ts:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
```

Configure and compile:

```
tsc --init
tsc
```

The `package.json` then contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.15.1",
  "typescript": "3.3.3"
}
```

And the `tsconfig` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "strict": true,                           
    "esModuleInterop": true                   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some interaction with the tfjs team, we could track down the issue. The problem indeed is in the typescript configuration.
If the flag: `"strictNullChecks": true` is set, typescript throws the aforementioned compilation error. Since this flag is included in `"strict": true`, which in turn is included in the default typescript configuration, this is unwanted behaviour.

As a temporary workaround, one can use `skipLibCheck` to only check their own code and not the dependencies.

The Issue related to this can be found here: [Issue on tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1241)